# Alfresco deployment with docker in a system that has a rabbitmq instance running

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, alfresco

I am trying to deploy Alfresco community edition with its official docker-compose file, the problem that I am facing is that in the host system there is a RabbitMq instance running (with default configs) an I think the ActiveMq and RabbitMq interferes with each other causing the Alfresco Content Service (ACS) to get stuck in "Starting 'Messaging' subsystem, ID: [Messaging, default]", but the ActiveMq seems to run properly.

this is my `docker-compose.yml` (I changed ActiveMq ports):

```
version: "2"

services:
    alfresco:
        image: alfresco/alfresco-content-repository-community:6.2.0-ga
        mem_limit: 1500m
        environment:
            JAVA_OPTS: "
                -Ddb.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
                -Ddb.username=alfresco
                -Ddb.password=alfresco
                -Ddb.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/alfresco
                -Dsolr.host=solr6
                -Dsolr.port=8983
                -Dsolr.secureComms=none
                -Dsolr.base.url=/solr
                -Dindex.subsystem.name=solr6
                -Dshare.host=127.0.0.1
                -Dshare.port=8080
                -Dalfresco.host=localhost
                -Dalfresco.port=8080
                -Daos.baseUrlOverwrite=http://localhost:8080/alfresco/aos
                -Dmessaging.broker.url=\"failover:(nio://activemq:11617)?timeout=3000&jms.useCompression=true\"
                -Ddeployment.method=DOCKER_COMPOSE

                -Dlocal.transform.service.enabled=true
                -DlocalTransform.pdfrenderer.url=http://alfresco-pdf-renderer:8090/
                -DlocalTransform.imagemagick.url=http://imagemagick:8090/
                -DlocalTransform.libreoffice.url=http://libreoffice:8090/
                -DlocalTransform.tika.url=http://tika:8090/
                -DlocalTransform.misc.url=http://transform-misc:8090/

                -Dlegacy.transform.service.enabled=true
                -Dalfresco-pdf-renderer.url=http://alfresco-pdf-renderer:8090/
                -Djodconverter.url=http://libreoffice:8090/
                -Dimg.url=http://imagemagick:8090/
                -Dtika.url=http://tika:8090/
                -Dtransform.misc.url=http://transform-misc:8090/

                -Dcsrf.filter.enabled=false
                -Xms1500m -Xmx1500m
                "

    alfresco-pdf-renderer:
        image: alfresco/alfresco-pdf-renderer:2.1.0
        mem_limit: 1g
        environment:
            JAVA_OPTS: " -Xms256m -Xmx512m"
        ports:
            - 8090:8090

    imagemagick:
        image: alfresco/alfresco-imagemagick:2.1.0
        mem_limit: 1g
        environment:
            JAVA_OPTS: " -Xms256m -Xmx512m"
        ports:
            - 8091:8090

    libreoffice:
        image: alfresco/alfresco-libreoffice:2.1.0
        mem_limit: 1g
        environment:
            JAVA_OPTS: " -Xms256m -Xmx512m"
        ports:
            - 8092:8090

    tika:
        image: alfresco/alfresco-tika:2.1.0
        mem_limit: 1g
        environment:
            JAVA_OPTS: " -Xms256m -Xmx512m"
        ports:
            - 8093:8090

    transform-misc:
        image: alfresco/alfresco-transform-misc:2.1.0
        mem_limit: 1g
        environment:
            JAVA_OPTS: " -Xms256m -Xmx512m"
        ports:
            - 8094:8090

    share:
        image: alfresco/alfresco-share:6.2.0
        mem_limit: 1g
        environment:
            REPO_HOST: "alfresco"
            REPO_PORT: "8080"
            JAVA_OPTS: "
                -Xms500m
                -Xmx500m
                -Dalfresco.host=localhost
                -Dalfresco.port=8080
                -Dalfresco.context=alfresco
                -Dalfresco.protocol=http
                "

    postgres:
        image: postgres:11.4
        mem_limit: 512m
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=alfresco
            - POSTGRES_USER=alfresco
            - POSTGRES_DB=alfresco
        command: postgres -c max_connections=300 -c log_min_messages=LOG
        ports:
            - 5432:5432

    solr6:
        image: alfresco/alfresco-search-services:1.4.0
        mem_limit: 2g
        environment:
            #Solr needs to know how to register itself with Alfresco
            - SOLR_ALFRESCO_HOST=alfresco
            - SOLR_ALFRESCO_PORT=8080
            #Alfresco needs to know how to call solr
            - SOLR_SOLR_HOST=solr6
            - SOLR_SOLR_PORT=8983
            #Create the default alfresco and archive cores
            - SOLR_CREATE_ALFRESCO_DEFAULTS=alfresco,archive
            #HTTP by default
            - ALFRESCO_SECURE_COMMS=none
            - "SOLR_JAVA_MEM=-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
        ports:
            - 8083:8983 #Browser port

    activemq:
        image: alfresco/alfresco-activemq:5.15.8
        mem_limit: 1g
        ports:
            - 1162:8161 # Web Console
            - 1673:5672 # AMQP
            - 11617:61616 # OpenWire
            - 11614:61613 # STOMP

    proxy:
        image: alfresco/acs-community-ngnix:1.0.0
        mem_limit: 128m
        depends_on:
            - alfresco
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        links:
            - alfresco
            - share
```

this is ActivMq logs :

```
activemq_1               | INFO: Loading '/opt/activemq/bin/env'
activemq_1               | INFO: Using java '/usr/java/default/bin/java'
activemq_1               | INFO: Starting in foreground, this is just for debugging purposes (stop process by pressing CTRL+C)
activemq_1               | INFO: Creating pidfile /opt/activemq/data/activemq.pid
activemq_1               | Extensions classpath:
activemq_1               |   [/opt/activemq/lib,/opt/activemq/lib/camel,/opt/activemq/lib/optional,/opt/activemq/lib/web,/opt/activemq/lib/extra]
activemq_1               | ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /opt/activemq
activemq_1               | ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /opt/activemq
activemq_1               | ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /opt/activemq/conf
activemq_1               | ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /opt/activemq/data
activemq_1               | Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
activemq_1               |  INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@73ad2d6: startup date [Mon Apr 27 09:57:23 UTC 2020]; root of context hierarchy
activemq_1               |  INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/opt/activemq/data/kahadb]
activemq_1               |  INFO | PListStore:[/opt/activemq/data/localhost/tmp_storage] started
activemq_1               |  INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.8 (localhost, ID:7f445cd32cc5-39441-1587981447728-0:1) is starting
activemq_1               |  INFO | Listening for connections at: tcp://7f445cd32cc5:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
activemq_1               |  INFO | Connector openwire started
activemq_1               |  INFO | Listening for connections at: amqp://7f445cd32cc5:5672?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
activemq_1               |  INFO | Connector amqp started
activemq_1               |  INFO | Listening for connections at: stomp://7f445cd32cc5:61613?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
activemq_1               |  INFO | Connector stomp started
activemq_1               |  INFO | Listening for connections at: mqtt://7f445cd32cc5:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
activemq_1               |  INFO | Connector mqtt started
activemq_1               |  INFO | Starting Jetty server
activemq_1               |  INFO | Creating Jetty connector
activemq_1               |  WARN | ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@8e50104{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: /

activemq_1               |  INFO | Listening for connections at ws://7f445cd32cc5:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
activemq_1               |  INFO | Connector ws started
activemq_1               |  INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.8 (localhost, ID:7f445cd32cc5-39441-1587981447728-0:1) started
activemq_1               |  INFO | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
activemq_1               |  WARN | Store limit is 102400 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: /opt/activemq/data/kahadb only has 20358 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 20358 mb
activemq_1               |  WARN | Temporary Store limit is 51200 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: /opt/activemq/data only has 20358 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 20358 mb
```

and this is the Alfresco last log that it get stucks for ever :

```
alfresco_1               | 2020-04-27 09:59:50,116  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'Messaging' subsystem, ID: [Messaging, default]
```